# How does firefox do css rendering

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, gecko

It may be a little academic. I am trying to find out the detail about css rendering in browsers. I have known that both Gecko and Webkit use hash map, style sharing to speed up css selectors matching.

In the following article, it also says that firefox uses rule tree and style context tree to do css rendering while Webkit not. I am wondering what effect/meaning these two trees are. Do they speed up selectors matching, save memory or something else ?  (Webkit runs well with out rule tree. So, what's the difference between these two core in css rendering?)

How browsers work: http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Here is another article I can find about firefox css rendering, which may help.

Mozilla Style System Documentation: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/style-system.html

Comment: +1 This is a very broad question but I'm also very interested in the answer.